# Cantor Intersection Theorem in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking at the Cantor Intersection Theorem from Apostol's Mathematical analysis.

Let {$Q_1, Q_2, $...} be a countable collection of nonempty sets in $R^n$ such that:

1) $Q_{k+1} \subset Q_k$

2) Each set $Q_k$ is closed and $Q_1$ is bounded.

Then the intersection $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty Q_k$ is closed and nonempty.

Proof. Let $S$ = $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty Q_k$. Then $S$ is closed since it is a countable union of closed sets. To show that $S$ is nonempty, we exhibit a point **x** in $S$. We can assume that each $Q_k$ contains infinitely many points; otherwise the proof is trivial.

The rest of the proof proceeds by applying Bolzano Weierstrass Thm and I understand it but it is the above part I don't get. Why is the proof trivial if we assume that some $Q_k$ contains only finite points. And if the theorem is obvious when some $Q_k$ contains only finite points obvious, isn't it even more obvious if every set is infinite?

Can anyone point out the problem with my understanding? Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean $S$ is an intersection of closed sets not a union. The case with one of the $Q_{k}$ is finite is easier because if you suppose it has $n$ elements then eventually there has to be some $j$ such that $Q_{i} = Q_{i+1}$ for $i \ge j$ (because there's only finitely many subsets of $Q_{k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Q_k$ has only finitely many points, then we have that $|Q_k|\geq|Q_{k+1}|\geq\ldots$, this is a decreasing sequence of positive integers, so it must stabilize. This means that for some $n$, every $m>n$ satisfies $Q_m=Q_n$, so clearly the intersection is non-empty, since it is equal to $Q_n$ as well.

The problem when each $Q_k$ is infinite is that infinite sets allow us to push things around, and since removing points from infinite sets *might* not change it is possible that at every step of the way $|Q_k|=|Q_n|$, but their intersection is suddenly empty after all. Think about the intersection of $A_n=\{k\in\Bbb N\mid k>n\}$ -- all these sets are infinite, but their intersection is empty!

Comment: This explains it thanks a lot but can you elaborate the meaning of infinite sets allowing us to push things around? I don't quite grip the picture.

Comment: I meant that it is possible to have a decreasing sequence of infinite sets whose intersection is empty, because infinite sets behave differently than finite sets in this context.

Answer (score 2):

If some $Q_k$ is finite, then write $Q_k = \{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\}$. Suppose $\cap Q_k = \emptyset$, then for each $1\leq i\leq n, \exists j = j_i$ such that $x_i \notin Q_{j_i}$. Since $Q_{j_i}$ contains $Q_n$ for all $n\geq j_i$, we may assume that $j_i\geq k$.

This is true for each $i$, hence if we choose $m = \max\{j_1, j_2, \ldots , j_n\}$, then
$$
x_i \notin Q_m \quad\forall 1\leq i\leq n
$$
Since $Q_m \subset Q_n$ it follows that $Q_m = \emptyset$ which is a contradiction.

Note how crucially we used the fact that $Q_k$ was finite - if it weren't, this process of choosing $j_i$'s would never end. For instance, consider $Q_k = (k,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$